# Font won't render on WordPress webste

Tags: wordpress, fonts, truetype

I am trying to add in a custom font for a WordPress site into Visual Code Studio.

This is my code-

```
@font-face {
font-family: 'tt0841m';
src: url('fonts/tt0841m.ttf') format('truetype');
font-style: normal;
}[enter image description here][1]


@font-face {
font-family: 'Nirvana-Bold';
src: url('fonts/Nirvana-Bold.ttf') format('truetype');
font-weight: bold;
font-style: normal;
}
```

Why does the Nirvana one work and the other not?
I only have the truetype format for each and looking at it in both chrome and brave.

New to coding so please can I have answers in simple language. If it isn't simple and obvious that is!

Comment: You probably have the Nirvana  font installed on your computer.

Comment: As @HowardE mentioned, you should have Nirvana-Bold installed in your system. The issue being, `src: url('fonts/Nirvana-Bold.ttf') format('truetype');`  the address were the code is searching for the font file, its not present there. You should see the error in your console. Fix that and it should work.  - You can tell us where have you put and someone may be able to point out the mistake in the `src` part of your code.

Comment: @bhanu Thank you for your clear comment and answer. You are right, they can't be found and I am getting a 404 error in the console. I was given one .tff file from the client for each font. I dropped them into a fonts file within my css file. I then 'enqueue'd' in my functions file like so-  wp_enqueue_style( 'charles-w-fonts', get_template_directory_uri() . '/css/fonts.css') ;  The rest you can then see above. If you could help me figure out what I am doing wrong or how to point the files correctly that would be brilliant!

Comment: @CopyV, Could you please share the tree view of your theme? That would help me understand the structure better. An image should suffice.

Comment: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2xq2A.jpg. Here is a link to the screnshot

Comment: @bhanu Above is the screenshot to the link. Thank you!